# Get all windows which overlap my window

Tags: windows, winapi, gdi

I want to find all windows which entirely or partly overlap my window (are on top of it).
As a special case, if I have two window handles (hWnd1 and hWnd2), I want to find if hWnd2 partly or completely overlaps hWnd1.
The windows in question are desktop windows (not children/siblings in the same process).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the windows that might overlap yours by repeatedly calling GetWindow(), using GW_HWNDPREV.  Use GetWindowRect() to check if such a window actually overlap yours.  There's no shortcut for two known windows, just check if GetWindow() returns hWnd2 while iterating.

Comment: Note that GetWindow can return the original window, if it is brought to front during this iteration.