# Determine window snap distance

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm working on an application that provides a snapping feature for its windows; drag one window close enough to the edge of the screen or another window, and it'll snap into place.

Windows 7 [offers a built-in snap feature](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/snap), and for consistency's sake I would like to get the "how close does this window need to be to be snapped" metric from the OS when possible. [`GetSystemMetrics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't seem to have anything particularly useful, however, and the [DWM docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are similarly unhelpful.

Is there any way I can programatically get this metric?

Comment: Read your post before going to sleep. The only way I have thought so far is to iterate all windows yourself or do this "http://stackoverflow.com/a/2317324/2538382" on WM_HITTEST, WM_SIZE or something. Then with all the rectangles do the math yourself.

Comment: @Helix I'm not sure how I'd go about doing the math myself, since I expect this metric might vary from system to system (?) and I'd only be able to manually calculate it on my own computer. If you're referring to the actual snapping behavior, that's no problem, I already have the code for that. I'm just trying to fine-tune the snap distance to match the snap distance of Windows itself.

Comment: Not the sort of thing that's likely to be documented - just pick a value that seems close enough and run with it.

Comment: You can at least base the number by some coefficient on some other metric like border size or display DPI. That way you make it dependent somehow on settings which people associate with mouse movement precision, alter for accessibility purposes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no such metric because the "snap distance" you are looking for is actually always 0.

When you drag a toplevel window on Windows 7 (and possibily Windows 8, not sure about that), it actually snaps as soon as the *mouse pointer* hits the edge of the screen.

The "snap system" *you* want, snaps the dragged window in place as soon as one of it's *edges* comes closer than *x* to the edge of another window or to the edge of the screen, where *x* is the distance you are looking for (typically 10 pixels or so).